# Calculating duration using date/timestamps in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: datetime, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm using XSLT 2.0, and am trying to calculate the  in WS-Trust messages, where there're  and  elements, so I need to determine the number of days, fractionally, between two date/timestamps, e.g., between:

2014-06-28T03:00:12Z and 2014-06-26T13:00:02Z

I've tried using:

```
<xsl:sequence select="fn:days-from-duration(xs:dateTime('2014-06-26T13:00:02Z')-xs:dateTime('2014-06-27T13:00:02Z'))"/>
```

but the above just keeps giving me "-1", i.e., an integer.

If I could maybe get the hours or minutes duration, I might possibly calculate the fractional days, but I tried using:

```
<xsl:sequence select="fn:hours-from-duration(xs:dateTime('2014-06-26T13:00:02Z')-xs:dateTime('2014-06-27T13:00:02Z'))"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:sequence select="fn:minutes-from-duration(xs:dateTime('2014-06-26T13:00:02Z')-xs:dateTime('2014-06-27T13:00:02Z'))"/>
```

and those both just give me "0".

Can anyone tell me how I can calculate the duration in either hours or minutes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`days-from-duration()`, `hours-from-duration()` and `minutes-from-duration()` are **extraction** functions: each extracts a single component from a duration. In your example, you are getting -1, 0 and 0 respectively because the duration between your two dateTimes is -1 days, 0 hours and 0 minutes.

If you want to calculate duration as fractional days, try perhaps:

```
<xsl:variable name="duration" select="xs:dateTime('2014-06-27T12:36:00Z')-xs:dateTime('2014-06-26T00:00:00Z')" />

<xsl:value-of select="days-from-duration($duration) + hours-from-duration($duration) div 24 + minutes-from-duration($duration) div 1440"/>
```

This returns `1.525`, representing a duration of `P1DT12H36M` (1 day, 12 hours and 36 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the two dateTime values to get a dayTimeDuration, then divide this by `xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')` (using the `div` operator) to get the number of days as an xs:double.